# phpmyadmin not showing tables that are utf8

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I set all my tables in a database to UTF8. When I try to access them through phpmyadmin it says that there are no tables for the database.

When I issue `SHOW TABLES`, they are all there.

Why is phpmyadmin showing no tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! I updated my version of phpmyadmin to the latest stable version and the problem disappeared.